# I can only capture the first output line of Node.js script

Tags: javascript, php, windows, node.js

I've written a simple test script for Node.js:

```js
console.log("Line #1 stdout");
console.log("Line #2 stdout");
console.log("Line #3 stdout");
console.error("Line #1 stderr");
console.error("Line #2 stderr");
console.error("Line #3 stderr");
process.exit(33);
```

I need to capture its full output from a PHP script but, no matter what I try, I only get the first line of each stream:

```php
var_dump(`node test.js 2>&1`);

exec('node test.js 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);

$descriptorspec = array(
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
    2 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stderr
);
$process = proc_open('node test.js', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
var_dump(stream_get_contents($pipes[1]));
var_dump(stream_get_contents($pipes[2]));
proc_close($process);
```

```
string(30) "Line #1 stdout
Line #1 stderr
"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "Line #1 stdout"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Line #1 stderr"
}
string(15) "Line #1 stdout
"
string(15) "Line #1 stderr
"
```

Am I missing some fundamental concept around the `console` object?

**Edit:** It isn't strictly a PHP problem; the same happens in the command line:

```
C:\test>node test.js 2>&1 | sort /r
Line #1 stdout
Line #1 stderr
```

It must be a Node.js particularity I haven't sorted out yet.

Comment: Would the CRLF have any affect on the contents?

Comment: Bear in mind that PHP is executing this process asynchronously, and you don't seem to be making any attempt to determine if the execution has completed or not. You may want to make use of [`stream_get_meta_data()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php)'s `eof` to check if the process has closed its output pipes or not.

Comment: @Sammitch - Perhaps that's the problem: the command ends and generates the status code while there's still pending buffered output (is that even possible?); [`console` docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/console.html#console_console) suggest there's something about that. But I've just tried with `util.puts()`, which is [supposedly synchronous](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_puts) and I still only got the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently a known issue in Node.js. There's even [a package to fix it](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exit):

> **exit**
>
> A replacement for process.exit that ensures stdio are fully drained
>   before exiting.
>
> To make a long story short, if process.exit is called on Windows,
>   script output is often truncated when pipe-redirecting stdout or
>   stderr. This module attempts to work around this issue by waiting
>   until those streams have been completely drained before actually
>   calling process.exit.
>
> See [Node.js issue #3584](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3584) for further reference.

With such package, replacing this:

```
process.exit(33);
```

... with this:

```
var exit = require('exit');
exit(33);
```

... yields the expected behaviour: console output is flushed before the process ends.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this is stated as being a problem only on Windows, but I just encountered it on Linux (Oracle Linux 7.4 to be exact), with Node 8.11.1.

My program is producing 723 lines of output with output to the terminal or redirected to a file, but is truncated at line 333 if piped to less or tee (leading to a lot of wasted debugging time).

The exit package mentioned resolved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure which code editor you are using, but you might want to check the line endings.  For instance, in Sublimetext 3, you could select the node test.js (and maybe escape that string node\ test.js) and make sure they are Unix line endings.  That'll  be through View -> Line Endings.

Comment: I've tried that (I'll no longer say this or that is impossible) but nothing changed. In fact, new lines are inserted automatically by `console.log()`, `console.error()`, `util.puts()`... If I do `console.log("One\nTwo\nThree")` I get three output lines (but only those from the first `console.log()` instance.